# Notification issue in iOS 15.3

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The below function is triggered when notification is received in foreground and background. But it is not triggered in iOS 15.3

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can receive all the notifications in below function :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Comment: This will be called only when the received notification is tapped not when the notification is received. @Nandish